# How to install processmaker/docker-executor-python

Tags: processmaker

According to https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker-release-notes/v/processmaker-4.1/processmaker-4.1.18-release-notes/core-4.1.18-product-versions
Script Executor for Python: Version 1.0.0 is part of the open source version :)

I have open source processmaker setup and working. But no python executor.
under packages installed I can see various things including Processmaker/docker-executor-node and Processmaker/docker-executor-php.

I don't know what these are. I have visited github and I can seacrh for executors:
https://github.com/ProcessMaker?q=docker-executor&type=all&language=&sort=

That shows a few but not python.
I don't know how to install packages, I am just guessing but I reviewed this page:
https://developers.processmaker.com/packages/the-package-skeleton

and based on this I made an educated guess and added the following to my docker build file:

```
RUN composer require processmaker/docker-executor-python --ignore-platform-reqs
RUN php artisan package-skeleton:install
```

Seems reasonable.
This errors though:

```
In PackageDiscoveryTrait.php line 376:
                                                                               
  Could not find a matching version of package processmaker/docker-executor-p  
  ython. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the pac  
  kage is available in a stability which matches your minimum-stability (dev)
```

So I know python is open source but I don't know the exact name of the package that I need to install to activate it. I also don't know if my method is correct.

I have not been able to find any pointers in the Processmaker docs on this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The error message you've shown does not look related to ProcessMaker itself, but to Composer (which is a PHP tool). Also, which steps of the installation tutorial did you take?

Comment: Yes, it's a composer error. Composer can not find the package for processmaker/docker-executor-python. I can't find it either so I have created my own (see my answer) Maybe the python executor was added to the open source functionality after all the others and they just haven't set the permissions, or maybe it was added to that list by accident, or maybe it follows a different naming convention.

Comment: I have found another place to search for processmaker executors - https://packagist.org/packages/processmaker/ again the python one is not listed. I have a feeling it's not availaible.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found the answer to this question but I have spent the weekend creating a workaround.

I built my own python executor for process maker and put it in github. I worked out how to publish it on https://packagist.org/.

I added the following to the end of my process maker docker image build command:

```
RUN composer require metcarob/docker-executor-python "1.1.12" --ignore-platform-reqs
```

This successfully imported it and when I was running I could go to Admin->Script executors and build the python docker image.
I could then create the script and run it!
I tried to make the script compatible with the comment that is automatically produced when you create new blank script, but it isn't fully implemented.

Adding the rest of the implementation should be easy and it's nice because now I can control the version of python that I am using.

Whilst doing this I learnt that process maker isn't built so that you can just add any languages as plugins. The default prompt isn't determined by my addin, rather it is calculated here: https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker/blob/8459de8b703f69e14f399bce9239460243affe5c/resources/js/processes/scripts/customFilters.js#L127

It's a shame we can't add languages without altering the processmaker source code. I was going to add my own version of python, and there are other languages it would be nice to have.

Comment: For anyone who can't find the proper python executor and wants to use mine you can find it here - https://packagist.org/packages/metcarob/docker-executor-python I have got it working well enough for me.